# VBA Macro that transfer data from 1 excel to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel macro vba please help.... My below code is to transfer data from 1 excel to another. However, when I execute the macro it transfers only 1 row i.e. A2 and B2 cell values into another excel.

[image: This the main excel from where the data goes to another]

[image: Output excel where it transfers only 1 row..]

My VBA code....

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim InvoiceNumber As String
Dim ForwarderCode As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Worksheets("SampleFile").Select
InvoiceNumber = Range("A2")
Worksheets("SampleFile").Select
ForwarderCode = Range("B2")

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:DestinationPath.xlsm")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = InvoiceNumber
.Offset(RowCount, 1) = ForwarderCode
End With

wb.Save

End Sub
```

Please help it should transfer the entire data present in column A and B....

Comment: But this is what your code does. It only copies `InvoiceNumber` and `ForwarderCode`. **What else would you like to copy**? From A1 to B last row? Then, you must  fully qualify the sheet you are working with and no need of any selection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want copying from A1 to C last filled cell, try the next code, please:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click___()
 Dim shSF As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet
 Dim wb As Workbook, lastRow As Long

 Set shSF = Worksheets("SampleFile")
 lastRow = shSF.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

 Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:DestinationPath.xlsm")
 Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 
 shSF.Range("A1:C" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=sh1.Range("A1")

 wb.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! It worked and reduced the number of coding appreciate that thanks again thanks a lot.....@FaneDuru

Comment: @Akshay Chari: Glad I could help! Please, try always using `Option Explicit` on top of your module. Then, try fully qualifying the used objects. Both 'Worksheets("SampleFile")` and `Worksheets("Sheet1")` refers the active workbook. It happens that `wb` has been open after and its sheet became active, but if your code gains some complexity and moves between worksheets, you may have problems if you do not qualify from the beginning the used sheets. In this way des not matter if `Worksheets("SampleFile")` is active or not. It is now `shSF`...

Comment: Thanks I have updated Option Explicit on top thanks...

Comment: Thanks I have updated Option Explicit on top thanks...